# Angular: Refer to current element in a template

Tags: angular

I have a form with several inputs. I want to validate each one separately, and add a class (for example, `is-invalid`) when the input contains an invalid value. I know Angular adds `ng-invalid` to the input class list, but as Bootstrap needs another class to show the error, I would like to add Bootstrap's class.

Is there any way to refer to the current element in Angular? I'm using Angular 5. My template:

```
<input [(ngModel)]="test" name="test" required [class.is-invalid]="thisElement.invalid && thisElement.touched">
                                                                   ^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Something to refer to the current element (`thisElement` in the snippet) is what I'm looking for. Does it exist?

Comment: You may try <input #thisElement [class.is-invalid]="thisElement.invalid" />. Take a look here: http://weblogs.thinktecture.com/thomas/2017/05/use-angular-template-reference-variables-anywhere-in-the-template-not.html

Comment: @ChristianBenseler That's returning a reference to the HTML element, but unfortunately it doesn't contain the propery `isInvalid` that I'm looking for. Digging a little more, I've seen that using `#thisElement="mgModel"` works and I get exactly what I need. Thanks!

Comment: Your question is somewhat unclear, usually in the template you have access to any public property of your component class. Just handle your error conditions in the component class itself and flip a boolean flag to display / hide errors. You might as well put all this logic in a Service as well ...

Comment: I'd suggest you also go read about FormControl, that is a very nice way to hanle form validation in Angular and it is something that you get out of the box...

Comment: @Lys I was trying to mark the input with a class when it has the invalid and touched states. The touched state doesn't exist in the model. Anyway, I will try FormControl to get better validation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To refer to the same element, you can use the sintax `#thisElement`, where "thisElement" may be any name of your choice. As you need to access some properties from the model it represents (`thisElement.invalid`), then you have to export it as `ngModel`.

So the template would be something like this:

```
<input #thisElement="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="test" name="test" required [class.is-invalid]="thisElement.invalid && thisElement.touched">
```

Comment: Don't be confused with `thisElement`. It's not some Angular keyword just a custom variable. You could name it `foo`, `bar` or anything.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, @tom, I've clarified it on the answer.